# How to run 2 async functions simultaneously

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await, winrt-async

I need to know how to run 2 async functions simultaneously, for an example check the following code:

```
public async Task<ResponseDataModel> DataDownload()
{
  ResponseDataModel responseModel1 = await RequestManager.CreateRequest(postData);
  ResponseDataModel responseModel2 = await RequestManager.CreateRequest(postData);

  //Wait here till both tasks complete. then return the result.

}
```

Here I have 2 `CreateRequest()` methods which runs sequentially. I would like to run these 2 functions parallel and at the end of both functions I want to return the result.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Return which result? You have two results.

Comment: Do you want to combine the results? Or return both?

Comment: let's say 1st result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need the first result out of the 2 operations you can so that by calling the 2 methods, and awaiting both tasks together with `Task.WhenAny:

```
public async Task<ResponseDataModel> DataDownloadAsync()
{
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(
        RequestManager.CreateRequest(postData), 
        RequestManager.CreateRequest(postData));
    return await completedTask;
}
```

`Task.WhenAny` creates a task that will complete when the first task of all of the supplied tasks completed. It returns the one task that completed so you can get its result.